# Count <img> within a <p> with no id or classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, count, detect

I was wondering if there is a way of counting `<img>` tags uploaded by users before a `<hr>` tag with no id or class(es).

Here's my code so far:

```
var num = $('#content img').length;
alert(num);

<div id="content">
    <!--The number of the "empty" paragraphs changes if users add more paragraphs-->
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <!--These are the images I look for-->
    <p>
       <img src="image.jpg">
       <img src="image2.jpg">
    </p>
    <hr>
    <p>
       <img src="image3.jpg">
    </p>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well for you DOM right now, it would be :

```
$('#content').find('hr').prev('p').find('img').length
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#content').find('hr').prev('p:not([id]):not[class]').find('img').length
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution using Javascript based on your DOM

```
function getImageCount() {
    var content = document.getElementById("content"),
        num = 0,
        hrs;

    if (content) {
        hrs = content.getElementsByTagName("hr");
        if (hrs && hrs.length) {
            num = hrs[0].previousElementSibling.children.length;
        }
    }

    return num;
}

alert(getImageCount());
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/Tzpfp/)